# How can assembly work on an Operating System?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

if the kernel takes control of the system, how can assembly language work?

Assembly language is introduced as a collection of mnemonics that a computer "understands"
and various macros to make certain tasks easier.

How can assembly control the CPU and memory if it cannot do that without making requests 
to the operating system?

For instance, if I want to do instruction `mov ax, #4`, wouldn't I need my program to send requests to the OS in order to be able to do so?

I'm really curious...

Thanks!

Comment: The CPU does *not* understand assembly; it is an intermediate form.  The CPU understands machine instructions.  Also, what makes you think that system calls are unavailable to assembly?

Comment: I understand that. However, I never seen any assembly request permission to use registers, nor permission to access/write to memory, nor permission to do any cpu operations. However based on response below, it appears that the kernel ensures that the operations you do are within the resources allocated by the kernel. The new question is, does this mean all instructions have to go through kernel?

Comment: write a C program that performs whatever, compile to assembly and you can very easily "see an assembly program" that is accessing whatever it is you wanted to access.  If run with the wrong permissions (trying to run kernel code in application space) will of course not work any more if you had not "looked at" the assembly step between the compiler and the assembler.  (most compilers, gcc certainly, compile to assembly then assembly, so you can save-temps and see the assembly code for any of your programs).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The CPU has mechanisms which assist the OS in protecting resources.  Let's use your example of an x86-chip.  The "general-purpose" registers, such as `eax`, are not protected.  But the debug registers, such as `DR0`, are.

When the OS is running, the CPU is executing in "ring 0" or what people call "system mode" to use a generic term.  The programs are running "ring 3" on x86, or what people call "user mode."

When the execution changes from ring 3 to ring 0 (more on how that is done later), the CPU drops the protections of user mode.  This is what allows the OS to change the debug registers.

However, the main thing protected by the OS are memory locations and device input/output.  For this reason, the `in` and `out` instructions are privileged, and may not be executed at ring 3.  Other privileged instructions include `mov` to/from control registers.

Memory is protected via the TLB, which is also used to define Virtual Memory (VM) address rangers visible to the user mode processes.  It is this table which controls the memory space visible to each process.  The TLB caches the [page tables](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging), which are stored in memory which only the ring 0 operating system may modify.  Similarly, the interrupt vectors and any memory-mapped devices are allocated to memory ranges that only the OS may access.  (An OS *could* map those pages into user-space processes, but that would potentially let user-space take over the machine.)

When you execute, e.g., `mov [eax], edx`, the address referenced by eax is looked up in the TLBs.  The CPU determines from the access bits in the TLB whether the instruction is legally accessing memory.   (These come from the [page table entry](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Table), e.g. the R/W bit needs to be set to allow that store to memory to run. Otherwise it will raise a #PF page fault exception which the OS can catch.  And handle by doing copy-on-write and returning to user-space to rerun the instruction: soft page fault.  Or deciding that it's user-space's fault (invalid page fault) and sending a SIGSEGV signal, terminating the process with a segmentation fault.  Or whatever terminology the OS wants to use, if not Unix.)

When processes are swapped by the OS scheduler, the general-purpose registers such `eax` are saved in a per-thread memory area maintained by the OS.  The thread being switched to is restored from its memory image of previous register values.

The computer would be incredibly slow if the OS interfered with every machine instruction.  In particular, access to general registers should be maintained as fast as possible.  The TLB look-ups for memory accesses are cached and not slower than the memory access itself.

To switch from ring 3 to ring 0, a software interrupt is generated.  This is the "system call" interrupt.  Interrupts run at ring 0, and are configured before the first process begins, by the OS.  The system call interrupt transfers control to the OS code.  When execution returns from the interrupt service routine, the CPU is returned to ring 3.

Comment: `mov [eax], 3` has ambiguous operand-size.  `mov [eax], edx` avoids that problem without needing `mov dword [eax], 3` (NASM) or `mov dword ptr [eax], 3` (MASM) overrides.  Also, the NOEXEC bit only affects code-fetch, for CS:EIP fetching the machine-code bytes that encode that instruction.  Since that instruction writes to memory, a good example would be the the R/W bit, which needs to be set to allow stores into that page. https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Table

Answer (score 5):

Your program can run whatever instructions it wants, as long as it doesn't access resources/memory outside of its [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29). If it does, it will generate a fault (segmentation violation or general protection) and be killed by the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly language is just a programming language like C or Pascal or whatever.  In order for programs to be executed no matter what language it is, the program running on the computer has to be in machine code for that computer.  Many/most languages are either assembled as in the case of assembly language or compiled as in the case of higher level languages into machine code for the target system.  Some languages (Java, Python and in cases Pascal) are compiled to in intermediate language, which is also a machine code, but then is interpreted at run time by a program written in some language which is compiled to machine code.  So here again machine code runs on the machine.

It doesnt matter what language you are talking about, system calls are system calls and memory restrictions and other operating system imposed restrictions apply.  So it doesnt matter if it is C or assembly language you can make a system call to open a file or print some stuff to the terminal or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but these assembly instructions are **direct** instructions to the CPU. They don't **need** to have another operating system to be working to perform. I believe that **[this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PPrrSyubG0)** youtube video can **really** show you how operating systems can be made using assembly